# Getting HTTP 302 Status Code when trying to access a certain Flask Endpoint

Tags: python, http, flask, routes

After adding wraps from functools, and creating a decorator function, after adding the decorator to the /dashboard route, I am unable to access dashboard.html and get a 302 status code.
The code for the following is below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import url_for
from flask import render_template
from flask import session
from flask import redirect
from functools import wraps
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = ""

#Database
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.user_login_system
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = ""

#Decorators
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(user, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect('/')

    return wrap

#Routes
from user import routes

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/login/")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/dashboard/")
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html")

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("404.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True

    app.run()
```

Upon removing the decorator, I am able to access the dashboard route again, but dont see anything wrong with the decorator I function I have.

Comment: what makes you expect a different result?

Comment: You're doing `return redirect('/')` and 302 is the code for redirect.

Comment: You don't seem to have anything that will set the `logged_in` session variable. So `if 'logged_in' in session:` is never true and you always redirect.

Comment: Within another class I have this:

    def start_session(self, user):
        del user["password"]
        session["loggin_in"] = True
        session["user"] = user
        return jsonify(user), 200